# Memory Leak in Javascript using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks

I have a huge memory leak and I am wondering where my mistake is. I am using the **net module** for network communication and once data is received the following code will be executed:

```
var currentbuffer = new Uint8Array(0);

server.on('data', function(data) {

currentbuffer = new Uint8Array(data); // store all incoming data into an 8bit array

});
```

This creates a huge memory leak.
I tried to solve the problem by adding one of these lines after allocating the memory, with no effect:

```
currentbuffer = new Uint8Array(0);
```

or

```
currentbuffer = null;
```

How can I solve my memory leak problem?

Comment: Strange, I've seen a lot of memory leak questions recently. Have you tried reusing the buffer? edit: This would probably involve initializing a fixed size array and setting the bytes when you receive them

Comment: Maybe your server emitting many 'data' events with partial data? Try to use Buffer for storing data and use buffer.write on each 'data' event

Comment: Headdump is a great tool to check to inspect the leak. https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-heapdump and tried this tutorial as well. https://github.com/felixge/node-memory-leak-tutorial ?